# window.open is not working on first click of button in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, button

Hello friends i write a code for open a aspx page in new window. But when i click the page button for first time its not opening the window but after that its open everytime when i click. I means to say that window is not opening on first click of button in asp.net here is my code

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button1.OnClientClick =
  "window.open('ezychat/frmchathome.aspx?FromUserId=" +Session["User_userid"] +
                     "&Username=" + Session["User_username"] +
                    "&IsReply=yes','','width=400,height=200,scrollbars=no,toolbars=no,titlebar=no,menubar=no'); isLostFocus = 'true';";
    }
```

Please tell me why it is happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because on first click it assign `OnClientClick` event of `Button1` and don't redirect you to windows.open event because declaration didn't performed yet when you first time click on this button.you have to declare this `OnClientClick` on `pageLoad` Event to redirect you on the first time when you press this `Button1`

Answer (score 0):

hmmm..
    this will work as per ur requirement...
    remove your onclick event as well...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button1.OnClientClick =
        "window.open('ezychat/frmchathome.aspx?FromUserId=" + Session["User_userid"] +
                           "&Username=" + Session["User_username"] +
                          "&IsReply=yes','','width=400,height=200,scrollbars=no,toolbars=no,titlebar=no,menubar=no'); isLostFocus = 'true';";

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this code

```
Button1.OnClientClick =
  "window.open('ezychat/frmchathome.aspx?FromUserId=" +Session["User_userid"] +
                     "&Username=" + Session["User_username"] +
                    "&IsReply=yes','','width=400,height=200,scrollbars=no,toolbars=no,titlebar=no,menubar=no'); isLostFocus = 'true';";
```

in the `pageload` method instead of `Button click` event.

What is happening is that in the first click you set the propety `OnClientClick` to the button, so next time you click on it it works.